# How to use release dll in the release build, and debug dll in the debug build

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, configuration

I have a winforms application that uses some self build components.
The self build components are in 2 dll's.
Everythings works but when I build a release of the winforms project than the debug dll's are put in the \bin\release folder of the winforms project and not the release dll's.

I notice that in the references of the winforms project both dll's are added (by the designer of visual studio) and when I look at the properties they are pointing to the \bin\debug folder of the dll's.
That will be the reason why the debug dll's are put in the release folder of the winforms project.

So my question is, can I configure my project in visual studio so that when I do a debug build of the winforms project the debug dll's are put in the \bin\debug folder, and when I do a release build the release dll's are put in the \bin\release folder ?

For now I copy the release builds of the dll's manually in the release folder before I deploy, but it would by nice if this could be done automatic.

**EDIT : 
to make things clear let me explain in another way my problem.**
When I do a RELEASE build of the winforms application than I get in BIN\RELEASE of the winforms application
1. a release build of my winforms executable
2. a debug build of the first dll
3. a debug build of the second dll

How to configure VS so it puts RELEASE builds of the dll's there

EDIT : this is how my release configuration manager looks
[image]

The winforms executable does goes to the te BIN\RELEASE folder, but it takes its DLL's from the BIN\DEBUG folders from the dll's instead of the BIN\RELEASE folder from the dll's.
The solution has 3 projects :
1. The winforms application
2 + 3 are the the projects for the dll's

EDIT :
This is how I switch from DEBUG to RELEASE
[image]

Comment: This should happen automatically when you switch between build/release configurations. Do you have changed something in the Configuration Manager menu? Of course when you switch configuration a safe practice is to do also a Clean Solution and then a Rebuild Solution

Comment: I havent changed anything in the configuration manager. So it is normal that the references of the dll's are pointing to the \bin\debug folder of the dll's ?

Comment: When you have the DEBUG config the products of the compilation should go in the BIN\DEBUG, when you have the RELEASE config the products should go in the BIN\RELEASE folder

Comment: I suggest to change manually the option back to BIN\RELEASE for each project affected by this anomaly. First be sure to select the RELEASE configuration, then open each project's properties page and go to the BUILD tab and fix the Output path using the Browse button. Then switch back and forth between debug and release config and check if the manual change has been preserved

Comment: The solution has 3 projects, both dll's and the winforms application. How can I change this for each seperate project in this solution ? When I switch from DEBUG to RELEASE it seems to do so for all projects in the solution. I have no experience in VS configuration as you probably already noticed

Comment: Set the configuration to RELEASE, open each project properties. Go to BUILD, change Output Path

Comment: The output paths are correct. When building a release the BIN\RELEASE for each dll is populated with a correct release build for each dll. That is not the problem. My problem is that in the BIN\RELEASE of the winforms application it puts debug dll's in stead of release dll's.

Comment: To put it simple, in my BIN\RELEASE for the main project, the winforms application, I have a RELEASE build of the winforms application, and DEBUG builds for each dll.

Comment: Then something else is at play here. Do you have a custom build action for the DEBUG configuration? (Project properties -> Build Events -> Post Build Event command line)

Comment: No I dont have that

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no more idea. Well, if you try to create a new solution with two empty projects with an exe and a dll you can check if the problem is localized to your current solution or is widespread to all solutions.

Comment: OK I will try that later. Thanks for your effort